# Tableau Log Function Incorrect

Tags: heatmap, tableau-api, logarithm

Here is sample [dataviz](https://public.tableau.com/views/logarithmic_order_quantity/logarithmic_order_quantity?:embed=y&:display_count=yes)

Heatmap of linear order quantity (region vs quantity)

[image]

Created calculated field `logarithmic = int(log([Order Quantity]))` and later on `logarithmic = int(log([Order Quantity],10))`

Heatmap where size is based on `logarithmic`.

Size doesn't change and number is incorrect, please guide.

[image]

Comment: It's maybe related about how Tableau is interpreting the value(It's 8120 or 8.12 ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr Sum the order quantities **before** taking the logarithm.

```
int(log(SUM[Order Quantity]))
```

Otherwise you are taking the logarithm of each individual Order Item, and then adding the logarithms. The aggregation function, sum() in your case, is specified when you place the field on the shelf unless you make it explicit in the calculated field.

Here are a couple of ways to use the log field, dual or triple encoding the log by size, color and shape. A custom legend works better with multiple encoded symbols than the default legends.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Alex! I shall try this solution soon. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to customize legends the way to showed. Where do I find such tutorials? Thank you.